# Cannot view Content-Encoding property on Chrome's Response Headers

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, gzip, google-chrome-devtools

Here In a Wordpress site, I have enabled **gzip compression** at .htaccess. I have checked gzip compression and `Content-Encoding` appears correctly [here](http://www.gidnetwork.com/tools/gzip-test.php).

[image]

But when checking compression at Chrome's developer tool, it doesn't show Content-Encoding on Response section:

[image]

Here are the .htaccess compression statements:

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddType x-font/otf .otf
AddType x-font/ttf .ttf
AddType x-font/eot .eot
AddType x-font/woff .woff
AddType image/x-icon .ico
AddType image/png .png
```

Why Chrome won't show gzip information?

Comment: Interesting post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaushal/archive/2012/07/23/i-don-t-see-content-encoding-header-in-ie-http-debugger-f12-developer-tools.aspx

Answer (score 2):

It seems that Google Chrome, as Mozilla Firefox already decodes content. But there is a difference between them.

In **Request Headers** the extra field `Accept-Encoding: "gzip, deflate"` shows up but in **Response Headers** there is no `Content-Encoding: gzip`

Using Fiddler is possible to click in **Transformer** button (from Response Headers section) and choose to encode content. After that click in **Raw** button to check if content-encoding is being used.

So Fiddler is nicer to check for response headers.

[image: Fiddler on the left, Firefox network debug on the right]